# TextField .textContentType modifier has no effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have the newest Xcode + MacOS that was released today. The textContentType don't seem to work.

```
TextField($binding, placeholder: placeholder,
                  onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
                    if changed { self.tapped = true }
                    else { self.tapped = false }}
).textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour is the same as for UIKit `UITextField` made with Storyboard (if one set only this parameter). Here is what Apple says about it:

> When you provide this information about the content you expect users
>   to enter in a text-entry area, the system **can in some cases**
>   automatically select an appropriate keyboard and improve keyboard
>   corrections and proactive integration with other text-entry
>   opportunities.

Consider it as a hint, not a rule. I always use it in combination with `.keyboardType` as below

```
TextField("", text: $phoneNumber)
    .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
    .keyboardType(.phonePad)
```